# How to find and return the page that a result is on in MongoDB aggregation pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a mongo DB aggregation pipeline that performs the following steps:

- Sorts a list of user stats objects by timestamp
- Groups the results by user ID
- Sorts by a specified stat's name
- Pages the results via skip and limit stages

In plain English, this pipeline returns a page from a list of user stats sorted by a specified stat. Each user can have multiple stats object, so I group to return only the most recent stats object for each user.

In Mongo Shell, this looks like:

```
db.getCollection("stats").aggregate(
    [
        { "$sort" : { "Timestamp" : -1.0 } }, 
        { 
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : "$UserId", 
                "UserId" : { "$last" : "$UserId" }, 
                "StatsOverall" : { "$last" : "$StatsOverall" },
                "Timestamp" : { "$last" : "$Timestamp" }
            }
        }, 
        { "$sort" : { "StatsOverall.Rank" : -1.0 } }, 
        { "$skip" : specifiedPageNumber }, 
        { "$limit" : specifiedNumResultsPerPage }
    ]
);
```

This works fine.

I now want to modify this query to be able to search the user by name, and get back the entire page that user is contained on. (This is for a leaderboard). So, if the user is on page 5 of the leaderboard, I want to return the entirety of page 5.

However, I'm having trouble seeing a solution that doesn't require me to either load all of the users in to memory and page them there (awful idea), or go back and forth to the database iterating through pages (almost as awful).

Is there some way I can modify my aggregation pipeline to do all this at the database level?

EDIT: As requested, added some sample data and the expected result.

Sample data looks something like this... I've omitted some fields that aren't relevant. The initial data is a collection of user's stats, where each user can have more than one object. My existing pipeline returns the 1 most recent stats object for each user sorted by a specified stat name.

```
{ 
    "_id" : "5c611e71ab0ffc430410e0ba", 
    "UserId" : "5c611e71ab0ffc430410e0ba", 
    "StatsOverall" : {
        "Rank" : NumberInt(1000), 
        "GamesLost" : NumberInt(30), 
        "GamesWon" : NumberInt(50)
    }
    "Timestamp" : "2019-02-10T21:35:06.599Z"
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : "5c6238658966ae5860795879", 
    "UserId" : "5c6238658966ae5860795879", 
    "StatsOverall" : {
        "Rank" : NumberInt(413), 
        "GamesLost" : NumberInt(2), 
        "GamesWon" : NumberInt(141),
    }, 
    "Timestamp" : "2019-02-10T21:35:06.599Z"
}
// many objects like this
```

The expected result looks like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "5c611e71ab0ffc430410e0ba", 
    "UserId" : "5c611e71ab0ffc430410e0ba", 
    "StatsOverall" : {
        "Rank" : NumberInt(1000), 
        "GamesLost" : NumberInt(30), 
        "GamesWon" : NumberInt(50)
    }
    "Timestamp" : "2019-02-10T21:35:06.599Z"
}
```

It returns the exact same type of object, sorted the same way as the existing pipeline, however I want to return only the page the the user is on. In the example result, assume the page size is just 1 result per page. So, the result would contain the 1 page that the user with the given `UserId` is on. In my sample result, that ID would be `5c611e71ab0ffc430410e0ba`.

Comment: will you please update your query with sample data and what is the expected result?

Comment: Sure, I'll post it now - give me just a moment to gets some together and redact it a bit.

Comment: Um that's not the job a a database to do. In fact your "fornula" for the `$skip` argument should be `( currentPage - 1 ) * numberOfItemsPerPage`. So you don't need the database to tell you what page you are on but rather "you tell the database".

Comment: @NeilLunn I fail to see what you are arguing. Are you trying to say it's somehow better to go back and forth between the app and the database iterating through each page to figure out what page the user is on?

Comment: Essentially, what I need to do is find a way to group the sorted results in the middle of the pipeline (before I page) into groups of size `n`, then return only the group containing the user id specified.